# Handling ActiveX Control Exceptions(C#) in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, activex

I've written an ActiveX Control in C# using COM Interop to expose methods/properties.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
class COMClass:ICOMClass
{ 
     public string methodA()
     {
          string str = "abc";
          if(str != "abcd")
              throw new Exception("invalid string");
         return str;
     }
}
[ComVisible(true)]
interface ICOMClass
{
    string methodA();
}
```

Is there a way to handle the exception thrown from C# inside javascript?  I have looked all over but I could not find anything?

Eg.

```
var x = new ActiveXObject("COMClass");
try{
   x.methodA
}
catch(e) { 
   alert(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `alert(e.message)` works for me.

Make sure your ActiveX class is implementing `IObjectSafety`:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[ComImport()]
[Guid("CB5BDC81-93C1-11CF-8F20-00805F2CD064")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IObjectSafety
{
    [PreserveSig()]
    int GetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, out int pdwSupportedOptions, out int pdwEnabledOptions);

    [PreserveSig()]
    int SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, int dwOptionSetMask, int dwEnabledOptions);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried what you did but when debugging, the exception was never caught even though I throw an error. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: If you do not throw the exception, does the scripting work? ie: if you take out the exception do you successfully return "abc"?

Comment: IT is actually a get/set property that I made visible to COM

<pre><code>public String DefaultFont {
   get { return m_DefaultFont; }
   set { if (value.length != 5) throw new Exception("error");
                   m _DefaultFont = value;
}</code></pre>

the scripting does work. It just goes through like no error has occurred

Comment: I seem to recall an issue with doing this through .NET properties. Could you try it with an actual method and see if you get the exception?

Comment: You are right. It works with methods but not with properties. Is there a way around it? Other than turning all my properties into Get/Set methods which I do not want to do yet.

Comment: Then you're stuck where I was. .NET creates accessor methods automatically for properties but I don't know if there's a way to get them exposed via COM. I ended up creating GetFoo()/SetFoo() methods explicitly instead of using properties unfortunately.

Comment: The Properties were exposed and I was able to set values and get values for it. However, it would not catch the exception even if invalid input is entered.

Comment: That was probably my experience too; I don't recall the details. If you figure out a way get properties throwing exceptions be sure to post your answer.